# Unable to access static properties of a component imported using React.lazy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-lazy-load

i have a react functional component in a file like this -

```
const Slot: React.ElementType = () => null;
const Component = ({ children }): JSX.Element | null => {
  const childrenArr = React.Children.toArray(children) as React.ReactElement[];
  const slot = childrenArr.find(child => child.type === Slot);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Hi</div>
      {slot && slot.props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

Component.Slot = Slot;
export default Component;
```

And i am using this compont by importing it in another using `React.lazy`

```
const Comp = React.lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "comp" */ './Component'))
```

I am rendering this component under `React.Suspense`, like this

```
 <Suspense fallback={null}>
   <Comp>
     Welcome
     <Comp.Slot>Robert</Comp.Slot>
   </Comp>
 </Suspense>
```

But `Robert` is not rendering.
Also, i am getting Typescript error for `Comp.Slot`, saying

```
Property 'Slot' does not exist on type 'LazyExoticComponent<{ (): Element | null; Slot: FunctionComponent<any>;}>'.
```

What will be the best way to fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `lazy` only works with default export and only with exact component being exported as it creates some sort of HOC around it.

What you can do is make this part

```
   <Comp>
     Welcome
     <Comp.Slot>Robert</Comp.Slot>
   </Comp>
```

standalone component and use lazy on it.